# SuiteScript 2.0 - Pricing Matrix - Set Price Levels to Null

Tags: matrix, mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to utilize a mapreduce script that will take my item input and open the item record, select base price, set all values to null or blank, then repeat on another defined price level. I am stuck on the first level, base price. It is throwing the following code: **USER_ERROR","message":"Please enter missing price(s)** Below is my code. What am I missing or not calling correct?

```
function(email, error, record, runtime, search, log) {
function nullPricing(itemId, itemType){
    try{
        log.audit({title:"nullPricing"});
        var itemRecord = record.load({
            "type": record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
            "id": itemId,
            "isDynamic": true
        });

        var priceId;
        var currencyId = 1;
        priceId = 'price1';
        log.debug("Currency:", priceId);

        //var priceId = price1;
        var basePrice = 1000;
        //log.debug("Base Price:", basePrice);
        //log.debug("Details:","itemId = " + itemId);

        columnCount = itemRecord.getMatrixHeaderCount(priceId, 'price');
        //log.debug("Matrix Count:", columnCount);

        for (var cnt=1; cnt<=columnCount; cnt++)
            {
            itemRecord.selectLine(priceId, 1);
            itemRecord.setCurrentMatrixSublistValue(priceId, 'price', cnt, basePrice);
            itemRecord.commitLine(priceId);
            }


        itemRecord.save();
    }catch(exception){
        log.debug("nullPricing Error Message:",exception);
    }
}

function getInputData() {
    try{
        log.debug("Get Input", "Initiated");
        //Item Search
        var itemSearch = search.load({
            id: 'customsearch_bwd_null_pricing'
        });

        log.debug("itemSearch", itemSearch);


        log.debug("GetInputData", "Completed");

        return itemSearch;
    }catch(exception){
        log.debug("GetInputDate Error Message:",exception);
    }
}


function map(context) {
    try{
        var searchResult = JSON.parse(context.value);
            log.debug("searchResult", searchResult);
        var itemId = searchResult.id;
            log.debug("itemId", itemId);
        var itemType = searchResult.recordType;
            log.debug("itemType", itemType);

            //Call the function
        nullPricing(itemId, itemType);

    }catch(exception){
        log.debug("Map Error Message:",exception);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Brad

Comment: Try doing JSON.stringify(itemRecord) right before saving, it helps identifying what's missing.

Comment: Adolfo,I added the JSON.stringify(itemRecord). I noticed it did not display the 1000 that the code was to commit to the line. So I added the following code in the `for` coding, `log.debug("column Count:", priceId + 'price' + cnt + basePrice));` It shows that all columns are adding 1000 but that should not necessarily be true. This particular item only has 2 out of 5 columns that have pricing. I need to identify how to only update those 2 columns. Any thoughts on how to perform that process?

Comment: Hello All, I am still struggling with these errors. Has anyone completed this task successfully in Suitescript 2.0? I see examples of 1.0 all over the place, but not having luck translating this to 2.0 (I am new to Suitescript). The above code is still intact. I am receiving the following error "USER_ERROR","message":"Please enter missing price(s)"

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the Price Level Matrix is that the matrix 0:0 position is 
Base Price: Qty0
If you try to enter a value to QTY1 NetSuite require you enter a quantity for that price level.

This code works for me with dynamic record:

```js
myRecord.selectLine({
    sublistId: 'price',
    line: 0
});
          
myRecord.setCurrentMatrixSublistValue({
     sublistId: 'price',
     fieldId: 'price',
     column: 0,
     value: basePrice,
     ignoreFieldChange: true,
     fireSlavingSync: true
});
myRecord.commitLine({
   sublistId: 'price'
});
```

Good luck.